# C# serial port loop in two thread sync problem

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop, serial-port

I am a beginner at C# and would like some advice on how to solve the following problem:

My main code include 2 thread, first thread is for sending data and the second one is for reading data from serial port. I use sinh=1; variable to synchronize both threads. First thread at sinh = 1 send the register name and read command for first register and set sinh = 2. Then second thread read the data and set sinh = 3. Than first thread at sinh = 3 send the register name and read command for second register and set sinh = 4. At the end the second thread at sinh = 4 read the data and set sinh = 1 and everything repeats again.

Problem is that second thread dont read data as it should. At the start sending and reading work synchronize after few cycles the read data are mixed (data that should be write in sin = 2 are write in sihn = 4 and data that should be write in sin = 4 are write in sihn = 2), then it works fine again for few cycles, then again all the data is mixed and so on.

I am solving this problem for several days now and I have no more idea what to do.

First thread (sending data):

```
private void read()
{
        while (read_data_on)
    {
        if (sinh == 1 )
          {

            serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x05 }, 0, 3); //set register 1
            serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2); //read register 1
            sinh = 2;
        }
         if (sinh == 3 )
        {
            serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x65 }, 0, 3); //set register 2
            serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2); //read register 2
            sinh = 4;
        }
     }
```

Second thread (receiving data):

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{
        if (sinh == 2 ) //read register 1
       {
           byte[] input1 = new byte[3];
           int st_bajtov1 = serialPort1.Read(input1, 0, 3);

               vrednost1 = (input1[2] << 16) | (input1[1] << 8) | (input1[0]);
               sinh = 3;                    
        }

       if (sinh == 4 ) //read register 2
       {
           byte[] input2 = new byte[3];
           int st_bajtov2 = serialPort1.Read(input2, 0, 3);

             vrednost2 = (input2[2] << 16) | (input2[1] << 8) | (input2[0]);
             sinh = 1;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it's not clear to me why you bother with the two threads. The first thread that's writing, is doing nothing else, it never yields back to the caller, and apparently you don't want it to write more data until it's received the response from the previous written data, so I would think that the whole thing could just go into a single loop in a single thread.

That said…

The main issue is that you have a race between the thread that's writing data and the event handler receiving it. For example, if your serial device responds to the data sent with `sinh == 1` and the `DataReceived` event is raised, before the sending thread gets a chance to set `sinh` to `2`, then the event handler will ignore the received data.

Secondarily, your code also fails to check the count of bytes that are read from the port. This could result in your failing to actually read the complete response of three bytes before you try to process it, because you could get the `DataReceived` event before all three bytes are available to be read.

The first issue you could fix by introducing locks and synchronizing the operations. But IMHO that's not really the best approach in the modern `async`/`await` era. Instead, you should read using the `BaseStream` property and use the async API so that there's only one method, one which doesn't consume *any* thread except when it needs to. E.g.:

```cs
private async Task read()
{
    Stream stream = serialPort1.BaseStream;

    while (read_data_on)
    {
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x05 }, 0, 3); //set register 1
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2); //read register 1
        vrednost1 = await ReadInt24(stream); 

        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x65 }, 0, 3); //set register 2
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2); //read register 2
        vrednost2 = await ReadInt24(stream); 
    }
}

private async Task<int> ReadInt24(Stream stream)
{
    byte[] input = new byte[3];
    int offset = 0;

    while (offset < input.Length)
    {
        offset += await stream.ReadAsync(input, offset, input.Length - offset);
    }

    return (input[2] << 16) | (input[1] << 8) | (input[0]);
}
```

Obviously, you'd also need to change your initialization of the `SerialPort` object so that you're not subscribing to the `DataReceived` event any longer. With the above, you don't need that.

Again, as I mentioned, at least given the code you posted in your question, in fact you may not need any of the asynchronous aspect at all. If you are already committing a whole thread just to the write operations and you expect not to write more data until a response has been read, you could do the same as my example above, except without all the `async`/`await` stuff:

```cs
private void read()
{
    Stream stream = serialPort1.BaseStream;

    while (read_data_on)
    {
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x05 }, 0, 3); //set register 1
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2); //read register 1
        vrednost1 = ReadInt24(stream); 

        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x40, 0x65 }, 0, 3); //set register 2
        stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x55, 0x1c }, 0, 2); //read register 2
        vrednost2 = ReadInt24(stream); 
    }
}

private int ReadInt24(Stream stream)
{
    byte[] input = new byte[3];
    int offset = 0;

    while (offset < input.Length)
    {
        offset += stream.Read(input, offset, input.Length - offset);
    }

    return (input[2] << 16) | (input[1] << 8) | (input[0]);
}
```

(Again, also making sure to remove the subscription to `DataReceived.)

If you want to start and monitor the serial I/O from a UI thread, then the async version is preferable. But the non-async version would work fine as a plug-in replacement for what you seem to have now.

In either case, the `sinh` state variable and all the back-and-forth thread stuff does not seem useful to me in your example. It's just complicating things, making it easier to introduce bugs, without adding anything beneficial. So the best solution is to just omit all of that altogether. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for an advice. Your code is working very good but in two thread is very slow (60 measurement per second). I try my code all in one thread and work very well, about 800 (measurement per second), but I have no wait logic in my code so all my data are mixing. Can you write code that will work only in one thread ?

Comment: The second option above should do all the work in a single thread. There's nothing else in your post that would explain why the _"data are mixing"_, so it's not possible to know what changes could be made to stop that from happening. The above is _exactly_ semantically the same as the code you posted, but with correct synchronization, so if there's still a "mixing" problem, it existed before for other reason. Have you considered inserting code before the loop to read any available bytes from the serial port, to make sure there's nothing left over in the serial port buffer?

Comment: The data are mixing in code I am sure. Your code work good, but is very slow because of calling function out of thread. Can you give me an example of code, that there is all write in read() while loop  and there is no calling function out of thread (example: vrednost1 = ReadInt24(stream); is not welcome ). Thank you very much.

Comment: When the function out of thread is calling "vrednost1 = ReadInt24(stream);", there is 16ms delays thats now the main problem.

Comment: I'm not understanding you, sorry. The second example uses only one thread. Why do you object to factoring out the repeated aspect of combining three bytes into a proper `int` value as a separate method? That has _zero_ impact on performance. If the loop executes more than once, it's because _it has to_. If you have code that doesn't do that same logic, but is faster, you got the extra speed at the expense of _getting the incorrect result_, i.e. you didn't actually read three bytes.

Comment: @mrkefca: _"there is 16ms delays that is the problem"_ -- if there's a 16 ms delay, it's only because that's how long it takes for the three bytes needed to show up on the serial port. It has nothing to do with the code per se.

Comment: I understand you now. I am beginer in c# so I apologize for the ignorance. I analyzed my FTDI and ADC with logic analyzer and work very fest. As soon as the last bit is sent, adc wait 1 cycle and that send 3 byte back. So that long need c# to proces that (16ms) ? is there any solution for speed up the c# ? I am running all at boud rate 11500.

Comment: It's difficult to offer specific advice, as I don't have access to your specific setup (and in particular, the hardware). That said, .NET isn't a real-time framework, and AFAIK isn't supported on any real-time operating systems. That means you will _always_ have delays, mainly caused by the way the OS schedules threads. I/O blocks a thread, and an I/O operation won't be seen to complete in code until the OS wakes the thread and lets it run again. Most likely that's where your 16 ms delay is coming from. If you want things to go faster, you'll need to just continuously poll the serial port.

Comment: For what it's worth: your question above has to do with synchronizing reads and writes, and it's been answered. You now seem to be concerned with the _separate_ problem of your I/O rate. It's not bad to discuss _a little_ in the comments, but ultimately that's a whole new question, and if you need specific details for a solution, you'll need to post an actual question about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228864/discussion-between-mrkefca-and-peter-duniho).